# What does the notation $\pi_1^c(\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}))$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, definition

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20107/surprising-analogue-of-q/) question on MO, it can be read:

> Indeed
>   $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}^{ab})=\pi_1^c(\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}))$
>   ($c$ stands for the commutator subgroup).

I'm trying to understand what this means. But I don't see what is $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$.
The spectrum of a field (defined as the space of prime ideals) is just a singleton, so I don't think $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$ should be understood in that sense. But I don't know what it means, then.

As Alex Youcis pointed out below, I was right about $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$. But then I don't understand what $\pi_1$ means in that context.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: It means the etale fundamental group, not the topological one. This is almost definitional once you define everything.

Comment: @AlexYoucis : but Spec still means the space of prime ideals?

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: As per your changed question--it's like I said. It means the (closure of) the commutator subgroup of the etale fundamental group. Have you tried looking this up?

Comment: @AlexYoucis : I'm looking this up right now. You could post this as an answer, if you wish. Is then the equality with $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q^{ab})$ obvious?

Comment: Yes. $\pi_1(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})=\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q})$. So, this just says that the closure of the commutator subgroup of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q})$ is $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}^\text{ab})$ which is obvious.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929683/why-is-pi-1-x-overlinex-mathrmgal-overlinek-k/1930320#1930320

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446824